# creating multiple image views with label with foreach

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to create design like in picture below (ignore label):

[image]

My question is can I solve this using dictionary with 32 keys and create this design with foreach loop or I need to create it manually? Im using programmatically way.

Comment: `UICollectionView` would be a better solution.

Comment: I would add that the reason a collection view is better involves everything from simplifying layout to (most importantly) reusable cells. Better performance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Direct answer to the question:

How to build imageviews and labels based on a dictionary using for each?

```
dict.enumerated().forEach { offset, pair in
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()

    label.text = pair.key // or pair.value or etc.
    // Do the the rest of the setup
}
```

Where the `offset` gives you the index of the element and the `pair` contains a single (key, value) object.

**Note** that dictionaries are **Unordered**!

---

#### Indirect answer

You may want to use a structured view like a `UICollectionView` for this instead. Then you can use the `map` to build the `dataSource` for the collectionView.